# Apache2: HTTP Basic Authentication against Active Directory without an additional user to search the Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, apache2

I'm currently using mod_authnz_ldap to enable HTTP Basic Authentication against Active Directory for a VirtualHost. Based on [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#activedirectory) it is recommended to set a user and password to enable the resolving of user DNs for the bind.

However AD offers methods to bind users without using a separate account for searching the directory in front. E.g. you can suffix a username with the Domain like that: `username@domain` and AD resolves the DN behind the scenes.

As I don't want to create accounts for my web servers I'm curious if there is a way to configure Apache2 using mod_authnz_ldap or another module to bind against AD without using an search account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the supported Active Directory [object name forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223499.aspx) for a simple bind, and skip the search for a user's DN by using directive [AuthLDAPInitialBindAsUser](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapinitialbindasuser) with module mod_authnz_ldap.

Comment: Cool - together with [AuthLDAPInitialBindPattern](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapinitialbindpattern) it might do the trick. Looks promising. I'll give this a try on monday.

Comment: This is exactly the scenario these two directives were created for.

Comment: So sad, that my server due to reasons sits on apache 2.2 and the directives were introduced later.

Comment: same question here, with some detailed example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71526149/apache-ldap-authentication-can-i-use-logging-in-user-credentials-for-binding/73580418#comment137330982_73580418