# apache ldap authentication - Can I use logging-in user credentials for binding?

Tags: apache, active-directory, ldap

I'm configuring Apache with ldap auth against AD.

I cannot bind anonymously to the LDAP and I do not want to put the binding user/password in the configuration file.

BUT, since the authenticating users HAVE the privilege to bind, I'm asking if it's possible to provide the

- AuthLDAPBindDN
- AuthLDAPBindPassword

parameters dynamically, passing the logged in user/password, maybe with some variable magic

```
<Directory my/htdocs/ldap >


AuthName "Basic ldap access"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthType Basic

AuthLDAPURL ldap://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:389/ou=for,ou=int,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(ObjectClass=*)

# User for LDAP binding. I cannot bind anonymously
# CAN I USE HERE THE LOGIN CREDENTIALS? 
AuthLDAPBindDN <user>  <-- can I use a variable for the logged in user name?
AuthLDAPBindPassword <password> <-- can I use a variable for the logged in user password?

LDAPReferrals off

Require group ldapUsers
AuthGroupFile "ldap-dbd-groups"
```

Comment: I don't know if you can pass variables in there but yes it would be perfect for that case. Though, note that mod_authnz_ldap uses AuthLDAPBindDN for binding _and searching_ the user to authenticate with, that is the entry matching AuthLDAPURL, so every user entry involved must also have the permission to search (ie. at least itself using a directive like `access to * by self search`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is supported by using two directives in mod_authnz_ldap.so

```
AuthLDAPInitialBindAsUser
AuthLDAPInitialBindPattern
```

> By default, the server either anonymously, or with a dedicated user
> and password, converts the basic authentication username into an LDAP
> distinguished name (DN). This directive forces the server to use the
> verbatim username and password provided by the incoming user to
> perform the initial DN search.

sample configuration like

```
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Authorization Realm"
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthLDAPInitialBindAsUser on
   AuthLDAPInitialBindPattern (.+) $1@DOMAIN
   AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ldaphost:636/DC=example,DC=com?sAMAccountName"
   Require valid-user
```

And if you want to use "Require ldap-group" or other authorization ways, you also need to use Directive

```
AuthLDAPCompareAsUser on
```

which uses authenticated user's credential for comparison (authorization).

Comment: In the example provided, one should read :   AuthLDAPInitialBindPattern (.+) $1@example.com. Take care, whatever ldap attribute you specify in the AuthLDAPUrl, to always define an AuthBindPattern string resolving to something in the format "shortusername@someADdomain". That format is that used internally by MS AD provider, particularly for the userPrincipalName attribute (the modern version of sAMAccountName).   Moreover, to speed up the search process, the AuthLDAPUrl can be written as this : AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ldaphost:636/CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)".

Comment: Same question here, with relevant link to MS docs "object name forms". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514422/apache2-http-basic-authentication-against-active-directory-without-an-additiona?rq=4